# Include external JavaScript / CSS or even images into html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently developing an html interface for a microcontroller. As it is quite slow I only want to have **one html file** that needs to be served.

Currently I am writing all my css / js in style / script tags. But this gets quite confusing with time so I would like to **split it up into .js/.css files** and include them via the src attribute.

Afterwards I would like to include all the external files and include them directly with a type of build script (windows/linux/mac). 
Is there a **slim solution** that can do that **without building up external dependencies**?

I am searching for a short script not for a framework...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct this webpack plugin does what you're trying to achieve.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin

Comment: I don't want to build up massive dependencies with npm and webpack.

Comment: You only have to use webpack while developing. Afterwards you can just take your html file and upload it to your microcontroller. What are you making by the way?

Comment: I everybody who would like to contribute to it would have to prepare a complex built environment. It is a cfw Frontend for the Toniebox https://github.com/toniebox-reverse-engineering

Comment: @Schr0nk Not sure what you expect.  I agree, Webpack is a real hassle, but now you state in your question that you don't want external dependencies.  How do you expect to find a tool to do what you want without installing that tool?

Comment: I am searching a short shellscript / cmd script that does that.

Comment: You're gonna spend more time looking for a solution than actually working on your project. Do yourself a favor and, just write your separate files and then copy paste it in your html.